# The operation is insecure

Tags: reactjs, dom, next.js

I'm using ErrorBoundary in my next.js application and I implement a network request that triggers an email if there is any DOM error happened. From there I'm getting this error with message "The operation is insecure." it's hard to debug a DOM error without any clear instructions.

I'm checking every object maping with ? but still getting this error.